# Error with BSTree insert

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

BSTree Insert Node:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class BSTree {
    private Node root;
    private int size;

    public BSTree(){root = null; size = 0;}

    public Node root(){return root;}
    public boolean isEmpty(){return root == null;}
    public int size(){return size;}

    public void insert(String s){

        root = new Node (s, root, null, null);
        size++;

    }

    private void insert(String s,Node node){


        if (root.setLeft() < 0 || root.hasLeft() > 0) // Currrently I have error on this line of code
            root = new Node (s, root, node, node);
        else {
            Node cursor = root;
            Node next = cursor.getRight();
            while (next != null && next.compareTo(s) <= 0 ) { // I also having error on the next.compareTo(s).
                cursor = next;
                next = next.getRight();
            }
            cursor.setRight(new Node(s, next, next, next));
        }
        size++;

    }
```

Can anyone help me solve the error? 
I'm new to BSTree, hence I'm not sure where went wrong. However my Node class is fine.

Thanks :)

Comment: What is the actual error? Also, why is your Node constructor taking in the Node it's instantiating as a parameter?

Comment: Where is the `Node` class defined ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to ensure that `root.setLeft()` and `root.hasLeft()` are defined and their return types are numeric, so that you will be able to compare them with operators like `>` and `<`.
2. The `next.compareTo(s)` fails because you're trying to compare `String` with `Node`, while the contract of the method requires to pass `String`.